# Requirement of let if var is already there

Tags: javascript

ES5 introduced use of `let`, but I don't understand if I already have `var` then why i need to use keyword `let` in javascript.

Comment: A simple google query would give you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var).

Comment: They are different. Let addresses the weaknesses of var.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared with let and const eliminate this specific issue of hoisting because they’re scoped to the block, not to the function. Previously, when you used var, variables were either scoped *globally or locally* to an entire function scope.

If a variable is declared using let or const inside a block of code (denoted by curly braces { }), then the variable is stuck in what is known as the temporal dead zone until the variable’s declaration is processed. This behavior prevents variables from being accessed only until after they’ve been declared.